# How do I reduce the severity of NotFoundHttpException?

Tags: symfony

I want to be alerted when bad things happen in my Symfony2 app. Right now I just look for `ERROR` in the logs. Unfortunately, "HTTP 404 - file not found" (NotFoundHttpException) gets logged as an error, as does "HTTP 403 - forbidden" (AccessDeniedHttpException).

This doesn't warrant an error; at the most these should be warnings. How can I make these log at a less severe level?

Example error:

```
[2012-07-02 16:58:21] request.ERROR: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /foo" (uncaught exception) at /home/user/Symfony2_v2.0.12/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 83 [] []
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found something that works. The [Symfony2 internals doc on the kernel.exeption event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#kernel-exception-event) mention that a response can be set on the event, and the [GetResponseForExceptionEvent docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseForExceptionEvent.html) say

> The propagation of this event is stopped as soon as a
>   response is set.

I cobbled together a listener that appears to do just what I want:

```php
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;

class ExceptionLoggingListener {
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event) {
    if(!$event) {
      $this->logger->err("Unknown kernel.exception in ".__CLASS__);
      return;
    }
    $notFoundException = '\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException';

    $e = $event->getException();
    $type = get_class($e);
    if ($e instanceof $notFoundException) {
      $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
      $response = new Response(Response::$statusTexts[404], 404);
      $event->setResponse($response);
      return;
    }

    $accessDeniedException = '\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException';
    if ($e instanceof $accessDeniedException) {
      $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
      $response = new Response(Response::$statusTexts[403], 403);
      $event->setResponse($response);
      return;
    }
    $this->logger->err("kernel.exception of type $type. Message: '".$e->getMessage()."'\nFile: ".$e->getFile().", line ".$e->getLine()."\nTrace: ".$e->getTraceAsString());
  }

}
```

Comment: random side-note: you should use `instaceof` instead of `$type === 'blah'`


http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php

Comment: [Lachlan Pease wrote](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.symfony2/9774/): "The alternative would be to subclass Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener and change the logic to only warn() on NotFoundHttpExceptions - this would have the benefit of not needing multiple exception listeners (hardly a big thing), but you'd have to keep all of the response generating code in your own subclass, which is a maintenance nightmare." (Thanks, Lachlan, that sounds even better!)

Comment: What does your services.yml entry look like for this?  What argument do you pass in for the logger?

Comment: Never mind, wrote my own version.  To see how to forward to twig exceptioncontroller and get the old behavior for exception handling (i.e. nice debug pages, forward to custom error pages) see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127336/move-symfony2-notfoundhttpexception-to-different-file/15146234#15146234

Answer (score 7):

Just add `excluded_404s` to your configuration:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
            excluded_404s:
                - ^/
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
```

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_regex_based_excludes.html for a reference

Comment: This is the modern approach.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way with less code :)

**1. Extend Symfonys ExceptionListner class and override the logging method:**

```php
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener as BaseListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;


class ExceptionListener extends BaseListener
{

    /**
     * Logs an exception.
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception The original \Exception instance
     * @param string     $message   The error message to log
     * @param Boolean    $original  False when the handling of the exception thrown another exception
     */
    protected function logException(\Exception $exception, $message, $original = true)
    {
        $isCritical = !$exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface || $exception->getStatusCode() >= 500;

        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            if ($isCritical) {
                $this->logger->critical($message);
            } else {

                if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
                    $this->logger->info($message);
                } else {
                    $this->logger->error($message);
                }
            }
        } elseif (!$original || $isCritical) {
            error_log($message);
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Configure the twig.exception_listener.class parameter:**

```
parameters:
    twig.exception_listener.class: "MyBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener"
```

Comment: It's worth noticing that everyone who's still using the 2.1 version will fail implementing this method due to the fact that the 2.1 version of the `ExceptionListener` class do not have a `logException` method (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use error level activity strategy (actually Symfony's in-built 404 errors excluding is done using this, so I guess this is a proper way to do it).

**config.yml**

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            handler: loggly
            activation_strategy: 'mybundle.monolog.fingers_crossed.activation_strategy'
        loggly:
            type: loggly
            token: %loggly_token%
            level: error
            tag: %loggly_tag%
```

**services.yml** (note that action level is set here, not in config.yml)

```
services:
    mybundle.monolog.fingers_crossed.activation_strategy:
        class: MyBundle\Handler\FingersCrossed\ErrorLevelActivationStrategy
        arguments:
            - '@request_stack'
            - 'error'
```

*ErrorLevelActivationStrategy.php*

```php
<?php
namespace MyBundle\Handler\FingersCrossed;

use Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossed\ErrorLevelActivationStrategy as BaseErrorLevelActivationStrategy;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * Activation strategy that ignores client errors (4xx)
 */
class ErrorLevelActivationStrategy extends BaseErrorLevelActivationStrategy
{
    protected $requestStack;
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, $actionLevel)
    {
        parent::__construct($actionLevel);
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHandlerActivated(array $record)
    {
        $isActivated = parent::isHandlerActivated($record);
        if (
            $isActivated
            && isset($record['context']['exception'])
            && $record['context']['exception'] instanceof HttpException
            && $record['context']['exception']->getStatusCode() >= 400
            && $record['context']['exception']->getStatusCode() <= 499
            && ($request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest())
        ) {
            $isActivated = false;
        }
        return $isActivated;
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/sobstel/d791d0347ee1f4e47b6e

Answer (score 1):

Symfony 5 solution based on Tarjei's answer:

Create a new ErrorListener that overrides the Symfony ErrorListener.

App\EventListener\ErrorListener.php

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorListener as BaseListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class ErrorListener extends BaseListener
{
    /**
     * Logs an exception.
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception The original \Exception instance
     * @param string     $message   The error message to log
     */
    protected function logException(\Throwable $exception, string $message): void
    {
        $isCritical = !$exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface || $exception->getStatusCode() >= 500;

        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            if ($isCritical) {
                $this->logger->critical($message);
            } else {
                if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
                    $this->logger->info($message);
                } else {
                    $this->logger->error($message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

services.yaml

```yaml
services:
    App\EventListener\ErrorListener: '@exception_listener'

    exception_listener:
        autowire: false
        class: App\EventListener\ErrorListener
        arguments:
            $controller: '%kernel.error_controller%'
            $logger: '@logger'
            $debug: '%kernel.debug%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Preferred this in Symfony 3.3 instead of excluded_404s parameter.

app/config/services.yml

```
exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: ["@logger", "@templating"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception}
```

src/AppBundle/Listener/ExceptionListener.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    private $logger;
    private $templateEngine;

    public function __construct(Logger $logger, EngineInterface $templateEngine)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->templateEngine = $templateEngine;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
        {
            $this->logger->info($exception->getMessage());

            // default twig error app/config/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error.html.twig
            $response = $this->templateEngine->render('TwigBundle:Exception:error.html.twig');

            $event->setResponse(new Response($response));
        }
    }
}
```